# Query for search the records in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two select boxes with the search button. In One select box is `fruit` and a second is `car`.
Now the issue is
1) If anyone select from the first select box and second select box then displays all records (Means it will display all fruit and car records).
2) If anyone select only First select box then display all records(Means it will display only fruit records) or
3) select second select box then display all records(Means it will display all car records).

Below query, I tried it is displaying It is working for the First issue

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE fruit='$fruit' and car='$car'
```

I need a query for 2) and 3) in single query. Would you help me in this?

Comment: you can achieve this with PHP

Comment: Try to use condition statement to check if the checkbox 'isset'. Then add the action to the query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM request WHERE (isset($_POST['fruit']) ? fruit='$fruit' : fruit='') and (isset($_POST['car']) ? car='$car' : car='')

Comment: if car is not set than it will give error because of "and"

Comment: that's why there is a shorthand condition statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you need to develop a little logic 
I am guessing as POST method

```
   if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$con =" 1=1 ";
if(!empty($_POST['fruit']) && !empty($_POST['car'])){
$con .=" and want_to_learn='".$_POST['fruit']."' and expert_in='".$_POST['car']."'";
}
else if(!empty($_POST['fruit'])){
$con .=" and want_to_learn='".$_POST['fruit']."'";
}
else if(!empty($_POST['car'])){
$con .=" and expert_in='".$_POST['car']."'";
}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM request WHERE ".$con ;
$search_result = $conn->query($search_sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Knowledge, What is $con="1=1 and"?

Comment: it is when u have no selected value means if any condition not true your query will look like  SELECT * FROM request WHERE 1=1 so it will bring all data of table. it is only for if you not selecte any value

Comment: Nope till now, I am trying to understand  how to use this logic.

Comment: you have to make dynamic condition as your need and put it in query

Comment: Mr.Knowledge, I selected from want and clicked on search then I am getting error: Undefined index: teach

Comment: when you post you are not getting tech. So what is problem with your post check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137730/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-knowledge).